# Overriding logback a log file for every log

Tags: logback

I use a file appender to note down the current timestamp when a particular event occur. Can some one help how to override the .log file where only timestamp should be noted at any given point of time.

If I delete the existing file programmatically and trying to store value, out of four events I'm able to store only first and third events and for second and fourth I don't see a .log file but I can see a logger on my console saying that timestamp is logged(for all the four events). Which is excepted because I'm deleting file programmatically, somewhere in the middle of the execution.

```
//timer expired?
if(diffInMin > lagAllowed){
     file.delete();
     return true;
}else{
    LOGGER.info("Can't recorded time for next \"{}\" minutes",(lagAllowed - diffInMin) );
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using `PrintWriter`. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size.

```
//timer expired?
if(diffInMin > lagAllowed){
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
     writer.close();
     return true;
}else{
    LOGGER.info("Can't recorded time for next \"{}\" minutes",(lagAllowed - diffInMin) );
    return false;
}
```